# Why Compiler change value of x to 1?

Tags: c++

Is that for 1 return to True value and 0 return to False value?
The output is 111

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x = 8, y = 10;
    if (x = 2 && y > x)
        cout << y + 1;
    cout << x;
    
}
```

Comment: `x = 2` is an assignment, not a compare. The rest is the result of operator precedence in the computation that provides the value being assigned.

Comment: Make sure you enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Since `&&` has higher [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `=`, your condition is being interpreted as `x = (2 && y > x)`, not `(x = 2) && (y > x)` or `(x == 2) && (y > x)`

Comment: Would it make more sense if you read it as `x = (2 && y > x)` where `true == 1`?

Comment: Right now we're sort of guessing at the answer. What did you expect to happen? Or more important, what did you *need* to happen?

Answer (score 3):

As the `&&` operator has a higher [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `=` operator, the condition of the `=` operator is being treated as assigning a boolean value to `x` as-if you had written:

`x = (2 && (y > x))`

Not as:

`(x = 2) && (y > x)`

For better experiences, use parenthesis explicitly:

`if ((x = 2) && (y > x))`

Comment: I think you mean "&& is a _binary_ operator"

Comment: braces are { and } - you probably mean brackets ( and )